# Instability analysis for plane Couette flow

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, stability-theory

I am investigating the stability/instability of the plane Couette flow. Looking at a flow, with at solid wall and a moving wall in x1 direction, while x2 being the wall-normal direction and x3 the spanwise direction, one gets following Navier Stokes equation:

$\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial t}+u_1'\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial x_1}+u_2'\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial x_2}+u_3'\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial x_3}+A x_2 \frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial x_1}+u_2'A+\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1}=\nu(\frac{\partial^2 u_1'}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1'}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1'}{\partial x_3^2})$

$\frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial t}+u_1'\frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial x_1}+u_2'\frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial x_2}+u_3'\frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial x_3}+A x_2 \frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_2}=\nu(\frac{\partial^2 u_2'}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_2'}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_2'}{\partial x_3^2})$

$\frac{\partial u_3'}{\partial t}+u_1'\frac{\partial u_3'}{\partial x_1}+u_2'\frac{\partial u_3'}{\partial x_2}+u_3'\frac{\partial u_3'}{\partial x_3}+A x_2 \frac{\partial u_3'}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_3}=\nu(\frac{\partial^2 u_3'}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_3'}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_3'}{\partial x_3^2})$

The Squires theorem states that of all the perturbations that may be applied to a shear flow (i.e. a velocity field of the form, the perturbations which are least stable are two-dimensional. Thus its seems sufficient to look at $u_3'=0$.

This leads to:

$\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial t}+u_1'\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial x_1}+u_2'\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial x_2}+A x_2 \frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial x_1}+u_2'A+\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1}=\nu(\frac{\partial^2 u_1'}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1'}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_1'}{\partial x_3^2})$

$\frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial t}+u_1'\frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial x_1}+u_2'\frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial x_2}+A x_2 \frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_2}=\nu(\frac{\partial^2 u_2'}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_2'}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_2'}{\partial x_3^2})$

Taking the derivate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ of the second equation and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$ of the first equation, leads to the vorticity trtansport equation for $\omega_3'=\frac{\partial u_2'}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial u_1'}{\partial x_3}$, you get:

$\frac{\partial \omega_3'}{\partial t}+u_1' \frac{\partial \omega_3'}{\partial x_1}+u_2' \frac{\partial \omega_3'}{\partial x_2}+A x_2  \frac{\partial \omega_3'}{\partial x_1}=\nu (\frac{\partial^2 \omega_3'}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \omega_3'}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \omega_3'}{\partial x_3^2})$

Introducing the stream function with:

$u_1'=\frac{\partial \Psi'}{\partial x_2}$ and $u_2'=-\frac{\partial \Psi'}{\partial x_1}$, one gets:

$-\frac{\partial  \Delta \Psi'}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \Psi'}{\partial x_2} \frac{\partial \Delta \Psi'}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial \Psi'}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial \Delta \Psi'}{\partial x_2}-A x_2  \frac{\partial \Delta \Psi'}{\partial x_1}=-\nu \Delta^2 \Psi'$

Ist it reasonable assume a similar approach as in the Rayleigh equation?

$\Psi'=\Phi(x_2) e^{i(x_1-c t)}$

This would leat to an ODE for $\Phi$, with $\Phi'$ and $\Phi''$, etc. being the derivatives of$\Phi$:

$ikc\Phi''+ik^3 c \Phi+i k \Phi'\Phi''-ik\Phi \Phi'''+ikA x_2(\Phi''+k^2\Phi)=\nu(-\Phi''''+k^4 \Phi)$

And how can one solve this equation?

Comment: I highly doubt that  the full nonlinear equation is solvable analytically.  Also the best approach is to  recast the equations in dimensionless form which introduces a Reynolds number $Re$ and solve for disturbance around the base flow $U(x_2)$.  That is, consider  a perturbed velocity field of the form $u_1 = U(x_2) + u_1'(x_1,x_2,t), u_2 = u'_2(x_1,x_2,t), u_3 = 0$.  You can assume the plane wave form for the disturbance velocity and then with boundary conditions you have an eigenvalue problem with respect to $c$ and fixed parameters $Re$ and wavenumber $k$.

Comment: The flow is unstable if the imaginary part of $c$ is positive.  The stability of plane Couette flow was first analyzed for linear stability, where the nonlinear terms in the disturbance equations are ignored.  This leads to the [Orr-Sommerfeld equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orr%E2%80%93Sommerfeld_equation).

Comment: Hey thanks,

I was actively avoiding the linear stability approach, since the plane Couette flow is linear stable. Actually I was trying to solve for ALL perturbations u1', u2', u3'. But it seems pretty hard. Therefore I wanted to use the Squire theorem to look at the most destabyzing persturbations.

Comment: There is a vast, vast  body of work on hydrodynamic stability going back many decades published in The Journal of Fluid Mechanics, Physics of Fluids, etc.  Search for nonlinear stability of plane Couette flow. It might help to look at some books like Hydrodynamic Stability by Drazin and Reid or Stability and Transition in Shear Flow by Schmid and Henningson.  What compels you to analyze this problem?  Whatever you are trying to do beyond linear analysis, it has probably been done before and it is not simple.

Comment: Hey thank you very much. I am trying to investigate the perturbations analytically, most of the research done so far focuse on the numerical investigation however. Actually I want to model the occuring coherent structures in plane Couette flow and then investigate the instability, I want to do this mostly analytically. Do you know of any analytical approach?